# apollo explorer say "isTrusted": true when i try use Subscription

Tags: websocket, graphql, express-graphql, graphql-subscriptions

guys, I have a problem when I want to use a Subscription I'm facing this issue I don't find a solution in any place, I'm a GQL user and i decide to use Subscription to make real-time website but I'm facing a a this   issue ,
hare is code

I'm trying to show apollo docs but I'm facing another issue(graphql doesn't find my resolver), so I try to use this pace of code in my mind it's work but the issue is it says
**Unable to connect wss://localhost:4001** also I'm trying to use **Unable to connect wss://localhost:4001/graphql** and **Unable to connect wss://localhost:4001/subscription**, also i try this three way with using **ws**

```
// my resolver
const somethingChanged = () => {
  // subscribe: () => {
  console.log("subscribe")
  pubsub.asyncIterator(SOMETHING_CHANGED_TOPIC)
  // }
}

const makeId = () => {
  // make id generator 36 symbols
  let id = Math.random().toString(36).split(".")[1]
  pubsub.publish(SOMETHING_CHANGED_TOPIC, {
    somethingChanged: {
      id,
    },
  })
  return id
}

const resolvers = {
  Subscription: {
    somethingChanged,
  },
  Query: {
    hello: () => "Hello world!",
  },
  Mutation: {
    makeId,
  },
}
```

```
// app.ts
import { createServer } from "http"
import express from "express"
import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-express"
import { typeDefs } from "./graphql/schema"
import "colors"
import resolvers from "./graphql/root"
import connect from "./db/connect"
import { PubSub } from "graphql-subscriptions"

const SOMETHING_CHANGED_TOPIC = "something_changed"

require("dotenv").config()
export const pubsub = new PubSub()

// 1  creating  one function for app
const startServer = async () => {
  // 2 // declaring app as express
  const app = express()
  const httpServer = createServer(app)

  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`Server was work ${Math.random().toString()}`.green)
  }, 2000)

  // middleware's
  connect()

  // 5
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => req,
  })

  // 6
  await apolloServer.start()

  // 7
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    path: "/graphql",
  })

  // 8
  httpServer.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4001 }, () =>
    console.log(
      `Server listening on localhost:4001${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`.blue
    )
  )
}

startServer()
```

I just want to test in apollo explorer but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed some of the steps please follow this code

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express"
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from "apollo-server-core"
import express from "express"
import graphSchema from "./graphql/schema"
import resolvers from "./graphql/resolvers"
import { createServer } from "http"
import connect from "./db/db"
import "colors"
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "@graphql-tools/schema"
import { execute, subscribe } from "graphql"
import { SubscriptionServer } from "subscriptions-transport-ws"
import getUser from "./helpers/getUser"
import { setUserData, userData, Req, setReq } from "./helpers/localData"
import cors from "cors"
require("dotenv").config()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4003
const startServer = async () => {
  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: graphSchema, resolvers })
  const app = express()
  const httpServer = createServer(app)
  const subscriptionServer = SubscriptionServer.create(
    {
      schema,
      execute,
      subscribe,
    },
    { server: httpServer, path: "/graphql" }
  )

  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(
      `Server was work, on port ${PORT}, time ${
        new Date().toLocaleTimeString().blue
      } , process pid: ${process.pid}`.green
    )
  }, 2000)
  app.use(cors())
  // database connected
  connect()
  // apollo server was created
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
    schema,
    // context
    context: async ({ req }) => {
      setReq(req)
      const token = req.headers.authorization || ""
      const user = (await getUser(token)) || ""
      setUserData(user)
      return { user, req }
    },
    // for subscriptions
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      {
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              subscriptionServer.close()
            },
            context: async (req: any) => {
              const token = req.headers.authorization || ""
              const user = await getUser(token)
              return { user, req }
            },
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  })
  // apollo server was started
  await apolloServer.start()

  app.use("/api", require("./routes"))

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    path: "/graphql",
  })
  // apollo server was start with express server
  httpServer.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(
      Server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}${apolloServer.graphqlPath}
        .blue
    )
  )
}
startServer() // start server
```